# Cannot establish master-slave replication on redis from my computer to amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, replication

I have set up the same version of redis in my amazon ec2 ubuntu instance and also in my home computer running ubuntu. I have set my security group in ec2 to have the port 6379 accesible publicly. I have added the line

```
slaveof ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 6379

where ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com is the public dns of my ec2 instance
```

to my redis configuration file in my own computer (the slave). Now when I run redis in the `master` (amazon ec2) and the `slave` (my computer at home) both in the command line, if i set a new redis key in the master, I get no update in the slave. The slave returns `nill/null` as no key exists.

What's wrong? Aren't the master and the slave connected? Or is their a different way to connect to the master through the public `ip/dns`?

Please note that I have also tried

```
slaveof ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 6379
```

where ubuntu is the user through which I have logged into to the amazon ec2 instance

But this does not work either. I have not set any authentication restrictions so the slave does not requires any password to connect to the master. I have searched online, rarely any detailed stuffs on redis replication and related error handlings.

Comment: how much data is stored in the master ? can the slave allocate such amount of memory ?

Comment: The master is amazon micro instance with around 512 of ram, and the slave is at my home with around 1Gb plus more disk space. If I HAD less memory in the slave, which is not the case though, would it be a problem.

Comment: BTW, I am new to redis. What I am doing is, install redis from command line in ubuntu in both master and slave. Change the redis.conf file in the slave. Restart redis server from command line in both slave and master. Start redis-cli in both, set keys in master, check keys in the slave. Does the redis-cli promt update keys in the actual redis server? Or is it just an interactive tool with temporary storage?

Comment: After trying for days and without getting any help anywhere, I solved the problem. Changed by bind-address to listen to slave server. Thats address, bind address was listening to local connection only